# 18.04 144hz Not Available (RX 480)

Tags: monitor, amdgpu

I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 18.04. I'm trying to set my 144hz monitor to 144hz as it is currently on 60hz. This is not possible in the display settings. The highest refresh rate listed is 60hz. The monitor is an Acer GN246HL.

I had used Antergos very recently with the same monitor and had no problems there.

Using the `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga` command in the terminal gives me the following:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480] [1002:67df] (rev c7)
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Radeon RX 470/480 [174b:e347]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I think it's to do with Ubuntu not having the latest open source drivers.

If you click on this link and follow the instructions for open source it fixed my problems.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

[How to Install The Latest AMD Radeon Drivers on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

Comment: I tried this, the ppa was added and the packages were upgraded just fine but there is still no 144hz option available for me, unfortunately.

The link you posted also mentions adding some lines to xorg.conf to enable DRI3. For some reason I can't find xorg.conf at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Comment: I used sudoedit in the terminal to create one. In the terminal "sudoedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf" you can then paste the block in.

Comment: Thanks, I did the same. Still no luck, however. Are there any other steps you took, such as adding a new prefix using xrandr?

Comment: Unfortunately that's all I done to fix the problem. You could try adding a custom resolution through xrandr. But I tried that before looking for alternatives and that didn't work for me.